# Any document oriented database fit for 512M VPS

Tags: mongodb, node.js, document-oriented-db

I have heard that mongodb use many memory, but I haven't much memory, I need run 2 or 3 apps on a 512M VPS, I want know are there any alternative choice, have easy to use API, and nodejs binding, and lightweight.

Comment: just because it _can_ use memory doesn't mean it _must_ use _all_ the available memory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna state the obvious, but why can't you use MongoDB? Just configure it to minimize memory use:

- For some tips, read ["Finding a way to make MongoDB/MongoMapper/Passenger work on a small VPS"](http://blog.seqmedia.com/?p=184).
- See a similar question: [Feasability of running MongoDB on Linode 512 VPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551296/feasability-of-running-mongodb-on-linode-512-vps)

Note that the high memory usage is one of the things that really make MongoDB so fast -- configurations with lower memory usage will degrade performance.

My second, obvious tip is that **don't torture yourself with too small VPS slices**. In total if invest a lot of time in building a system that works for small VPS while saving only some dollars in hosting fees, *you are making bad business*. Just to highlight let's make a short example: let's say you invest 100 hours of work in finding and configuring a document database that suits your 512M VPS, instead of buying like 2 Gig VPS. If you - by using smaller VPS - earn 25 dollars a month and your hourly salary is like 10 dollars, it would take over 3 years for you to gain your time commitment back in VPS fees. In 99% it is just not worth it!